# Jupyter with docker: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'column'

Tags: python, docker, jupyter-notebook, tensorflow2.0

I recently installed TensorFlow with GPU support using docker:

```
docker pull tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu-jupyter
```

But sometimes when I start a jupyter notebook server using the command:

```
docker run --gpus all -it -p 8888:8888 tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu-jupyter jupyter notebook --notebook-dir=/tf --ip 0.0.0.0 --allow-root --NotebookApp.allow_origin='https://colab.research.google.com'
```

I see the following exception on the terminal:

```
[IPKernelApp] ERROR | Exception in message handler:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 272, in dispatch_shell
    yield gen.maybe_future(handler(stream, idents, msg))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 762, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 234, in wrapper
    yielded = ctx_run(next, result)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 162, in _fake_ctx_run
    return f(*args, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 580, in complete_request
    matches = yield gen.maybe_future(self.do_complete(code, cursor_pos))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line 348, in do_complete
    return self._experimental_do_complete(code, cursor_pos)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line 373, in _experimental_do_complete
    completions = list(_rectify_completions(code, raw_completions))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/IPython/core/completer.py", line 484, in rectify_completions
    completions = list(completions)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/IPython/core/completer.py", line 1818, in completions
    for c in self._completions(text, offset, _timeout=self.jedi_compute_type_timeout/1000):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/IPython/core/completer.py", line 1862, in _completions
    full_text=full_text, cursor_line=cursor_line, cursor_pos=cursor_column)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/IPython/core/completer.py", line 2030, in _complete
    cursor_pos, cursor_line, full_text)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/IPython/core/completer.py", line 1374, in _jedi_matches
    text[:offset], namespaces, column=cursor_column, line=cursor_line + 1)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/jedi/api/__init__.py", line 726, in __init__
    project=Project(Path.cwd()), **kwds)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'column'
```

After that, I have to restart the server or reconnect from google colab.

Any ideas where the error might come from and how to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be an incompatibility between jedi and ipython, see [this issue](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/12740).

The fix would be to pin jedi to 0.17.2, so either run:

```
pip install jedi==0.17.2
```

Or if you are using poetry add this to your pyproject.toml:

```
jedi = "<=0.17.2"
```

But since you are using a docker image that image will need to be updated. It seems to be [gpu-jupyter.Dockerfile](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/tools/dockerfiles/dockerfiles/gpu-jupyter.Dockerfile).

I would raise an issue on that project and see if they can pin `jedi` like they did for `nbformat`, or you could just fork it. They should probably upgrade python as well, 3.6 is getting a bit long in the tooth.

Comment: I built the image you showed me but I still have the same error!

Comment: How did you modify the Dockerfile exactly? You should probably be able to add jedi==0.17.2 at the end of line 149 and it should work...

Comment: Ah sorry I'm a newbie to docker, didn't know I had to modify the file! I just did it and it worked, thank you! One more question though: If I try to import tensorflow with the new image I have the error `No module named 'tensorflow'`! any idea how to solve this? I didn't have this error with the previous image!

Comment: Not sure, did you build the “previous image” yourself or was it provided? Did you try without the `jedi==0.17.2` and see if that worked? I would be very surprised if it was the change to pin Jedi that broke it.

Comment: The "previous image" was provided. I pulled it with this command: `docker pull tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu-jupyter`! I also tried without `jedi==0.17.2`: same problem

Comment: The error `No module named 'tensorflow'` occurs because The `devel-*` files do not have Tensorflow installed by default, please refer to this answer: [https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/25558#issuecomment-493169762](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/25558#issuecomment-493169762). So I just used the file [gpu-jupyter.Dockerfile](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/tools/dockerfiles/dockerfiles/gpu-jupyter.Dockerfile) instead of the file `devel-gpu-jupyter.Dockerfile` (The one in the answer above)

Comment: I updated the answer to point at the correct Dockerfile

Answer (score 1):

I will add more details to @daphtdazz's answer. I had to do the following steps to solve this issue:

**1**. Download TensorFlow from github:

```
git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow.git
```

**2**. Edit the file `gpu-jupyter.Dockerfile` to add `jedi==0.17.2` at the end of line 104:

```
vim tensorflow/tensorflow/tools/dockerfiles/dockerfiles/gpu-jupyter.Dockerfile
```

**3**. Placed myself inside the `dockerfiles` folder :

```
cd tensorflow/tensorflow/tools/dockerfiles/
```

**4**. Build the image:

```
docker build -f ./dockerfiles/gpu-jupyter.Dockerfile -t tf .
```